# Combinatorics on sets

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets containing $2$ elements and $4$ elements respectively. Find the number of subsets of $A\times B$ having $3$ or more elements.

My actual problem is how can a cartesian product have more than two elements in a subset. I am hopefully wrong in my understanding of cartesian products. Hence, I would appreciate if someone would help me in this context. :))

Comment: The elements of a Caresian product are the tuples, not the members of the tuples.  It's the whole pair and nothing but the pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cartesian product $A\times B$ two elements in every **pair** $(x,y)$, but a **subset** can have any number of elements up to the number in the whole set.  For example, if
$$A=\{\,a,b\,\}\quad\hbox{and}\quad B=\{\,1,2,3,4\,\}$$
then
$$\{\,(a,1),(a,3),(b,4)\,\}$$
is a subset of $A\times B$ containing $3$ elements.

**Hint**.  To find the number of subsets of a set $S$ which have three or more elements, it doesn't matter what the set $S$ is, it only matters how many elements it has.  So, how many elements has $A\times B$?

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Its really helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

A×B has 2*4=8 elements.
How can you use this?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @mookid:L This answer is not a critique or a request for clarification; it is a hint. I believe it is permitted to give hints instead of a compolete answer.

Comment: I would see your answer as a comment on OP's post.

Comment: I'll take care of that the next time. :)